# What is a CPU intensive task in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I new to Node.js and I am sorry for what seems like a noob question but I would really feel better with your advice.

I think I grasped most of the basics of Node.js. I understand that it is single threaded and therefore that all of the I/O jobs are asynchronous in order not to block the event loop.

I also understand that because of this single-threaded nature, Node.js is not very well suited for CPU intensive tasks which would block the event loop.

My question is simple: I'm working on a websocket application and on most of the requests, I have to perform a loop with some computation. According to my tests, this loop may take from 30 to 80 ms to complete. Should I consider this as a CPU intensive task? (if yes, I guess I should then try to delegate it to a child process or split the computation in several parts with process.nextTick).

Comment: I don't know whether it is or not CPU intensive, but if you want better performance, then you might consider writing C/C++ addon.

Comment: You should also factor the number of concurrent users that you are expecting to handle. 30-80ms for 10 users is probably not a big deal, but for hundreds of thousands it's a different deal.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what kind of QOS that you are looking for.
I'd say that for a personnal projet this is fine. If you are using websockets for a game for example this might be killer.

The module [cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_cluster) could be used to get around this. This is more work but that module makes is as easy as possible to get a cluster of process and the communication between them.